# php : link preview or url preview not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-get-contents, firewall

Using ubuntu server, 18.04, php 7.2. *php.ini* includes `allow_url_fopen= on`. Disabling the firewall didn't work. I also tried searching for 6 hours now applied some random answers didn't work.

This is my code so far:

```
if (preg_match('@(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.//]))((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.\,]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($urlData)), $results)) {

            $page = $results[0];

            $page = $this->addScheme($page);

            // $default_socket_timeout = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');
            // ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 3);

            $content = file_get_contents("https://api.urlmeta.org/?url=".$page);

            // ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $default_socket_timeout);

            if ($content) {

                $data = json_decode($content, true);

                $urlResult = $data['result'];
                $urlResponse = $data['meta'];

                if ($urlResult['status'] === "OK") {

                    $urlLink = $page;

                    if (isset($urlResponse['image'])) {

                        $urlImage = $urlResponse['image'];
                    }

                    if (isset($urlResponse['description'])) {

                        $urlDescription = $urlResponse['description'];
                    }

                    if (isset($urlResponse['title'])) {

                        $urlTitle = $urlResponse['title'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you get back in your `$content` variable? e.g. `var_dump($content)`

Comment: @peter nothing only the link

Comment: OK, and what does `$page` look like after you add the scheme?

Comment: sorry i am new, So can't tell in expert words, but page is any page on the internet like blog and news and so

Comment: Can you post an example URL that you are trying to get that is not working?

Comment: check that api first whether its alive or not.. and if its alive then check the required format of its parameters ($page) which you have to pass, is it in api-required format or not..